# IOException sending GCM notifications

Tags: java, android, json, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send some JSON notifications to the GCM servers and I'm getting this list of errors

```
Response Code: 400
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at controller.Notification.post(Notification.java:181)
        at controller.App.main(App.java:17)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
        at controller.Notification.post(Notification.java:179)
        ... 1 more
```

Weird thing is, this only happens if I try to send to a single device. it works if I try to send to multiple devices, using the `registration_id` field. The reference says error 400 means the JSON couldn't be parsed, but I tried printing it out and it seems fine:

Multicast sending: (response code: 200, invalid registration)

```
{"registration_ids":["asdlfiwuhfs"]}
```

Sending to single device: (responce code: 400, errors above)

```
{"to":"asdlfiwuhfs"}
```

The functions to send to a single or multiple devices have only one different line. One of them adds the `to` field, the other a `registration_id` field.

```
obj.put("registration_ids", regIds); // multiple devices
obj.put("to", regId);                // single device
```

What could be the problem?

Edit:

The third line below is line 181 mentioned in the errors:

```
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); // 181
```

Comment: What is the form of the url when you send to multiple devices? Please post it

Comment: Same one as here. https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send

Comment: `400` is bad request, not that `the JSON couldn't be parsed` by the way...

Comment: From the [HTTP Server Reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref): Only applies for JSON requests. Indicates that the request could not be parsed as JSON, or it contained invalid fields (for instance, passing a string where a number was expected). The exact failure reason is described in the response and the problem should be addressed before the request can be retried.

Comment: And, can you add a breakpoint and check what is the content of the response? Or catch the exception for doing it?

Comment: I do catch the exception, and the errors above are the stack trace it prints. The error happens before I can print the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution looking at [this code](https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/samples/android/gcm-demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/logic/HttpRequest.java) on github.

It seems `getInputStream()` is only used when the response code is `200`. Otherwise, `getErrorStream()` should be used.

So changing my code to this fixed it.

```
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = null;
if (responseCode == 200)
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
else
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
```